# How can I find unique user on my webpage visits in hive?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

The schema of table is like this `page(id,userid)`

e.g. if the content of tables are :

```
1 NULL
1 NULL
2 NULL
2 U2
2 U3
3 U1
3 U2
4 U1
4 U4
5 NULL
5 NULL
```

The answer should be = 6
Explanation with visit ID 1 & 5 we have 2 users and other 4 unique users.

How can get this done in hive?

Comment: What's the issue you are facing? Could you try rephrasing the question and explaining the methods you have tried?

Comment: I can find the users in the case where we have one or more NULLs or No NULL. But I am not able to find out how to get the users with all NULLs.